# C# Creating Entity Object in one line

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Entity class

```
public class SiteMenu
{
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string NavURL { get; set; }
    public int ParentMenuID { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a collection of SiteMenu by the following  code:

```
List<SiteMenu> all = new List<SiteMenu>();
```

To create and add an SiteMenu object to the List is this the correct format/syntax

```
all.Add(new SiteMenu(MenuID=1, MenuName="Test1", NavURL="http://test", ParentMenuID=0));
```

I like to use one line and keep adding to the list.

THanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax to create the list and add the initial elements in one line:

```
var all = new List<SiteMenu> { new SiteMenu { MenuID = 1, MenuName = "Test1", NavURL = "http://test", ParentMenuID = 0} };
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, for the love of all that is holy put in some line breaks so the poor developer who has to deal with it after you leave has some hope of reading it and understanding what you're doing.

Comment: @CraigW. Sure but that was exactly what OP was asking for.

Comment: That was more targeted towards the OP in case he decides to follow this suggestion. It's still one logical line (one semi-colon) but at least it would be readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SiteMenu> list = new List<SiteMenu> {
    all.Add(new SiteMenu(MenuID=1, MenuName="Test1", NavURL="http://test", ParentMenuID=0));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a constructor.

```
public class SiteMenu
{
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string NavURL { get; set; }
    public int ParentMenuID { get; set; }

    public SiteMenu(int menuID, string menuName, string navURL, int parentMenuID) {
        MenuID = menuID;
        MenuName = menuName;
        NavURL = navURL;
        ParentMenuID = parentMenuID;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<SiteMenu> all = new List<SiteMenu>();
all.Add(new SiteMenu(1, "Test1", "http://test", 0));
```